# Flutter Charts - Year on Year Sales Comparison

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I am comparing 30 day history sales for the current year VS any other selected year by the user using a stacked time series line chart.

The chart looks like this when it works:

[image]

Two fetches are done from the server:

1. A list that always has 30 days for the selected date for the **current** year.
2. A second list has 30 days for the selected date for the selected year.

The data returned, looks like the two lists below:

```
static List<charts.Series<TimeSeriesSales, DateTime>> _createSampleData() {

final currentYear = [
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 15), sales: 600000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 14), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 13), sales: 450000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 12), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 10), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 11), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 12), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 10), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 09), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 08), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 07), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 06), sales: 400000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 05), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 04), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 03), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 02), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2020, 01, 01), sales: 200000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 31), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 30), sales: 600000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 29), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 28), sales: 400000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 27), sales: 600000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 26), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 25), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 24), sales: 600000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 23), sales: 800000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 22), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 21), sales: 800000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 20), sales: 900000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 12, 19), sales: 900000),

];

final selectedYear = [
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 15), sales: 600000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 14), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 13), sales: 450000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 12), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 10), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 11), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 12), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 10), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 09), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 08), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 07), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 06), sales: 400000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 05), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 04), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 03), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 02), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2019, 01, 01), sales: 200000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 31), sales: 500000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 30), sales: 600000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 29), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 28), sales: 400000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 27), sales: 600000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 26), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 25), sales: 300000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 24), sales: 600000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 23), sales: 800000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 22), sales: 700000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 21), sales: 800000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 20), sales: 900000),
   TimeSeriesSales(timeCurrent: DateTime(2018, 12, 19), sales: 900000),
];



    List<charts.Series<SalesChartObjects, DateTime>> sales = [

  charts.Series(
      id: "Last Year",
      data: salesChartService.chartObjectsPreviousYear,
      domainFn: (SalesChartObjects data, _) => data.dt,
      measureFn: (SalesChartObjects data, _) => data.amount,
      labelAccessorFn: (SalesChartObjects data, _) => data.amount.toString(),
      colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.gray.shadeDefault),

  charts.Series(
      id: "This Year",
      data: salesChartService.chartObjectsCurrentYear,
      domainFn: (SalesChartObjects data, _) => data.dt,
      measureFn: (SalesChartObjects data, _) => data.amount,
      labelAccessorFn: (SalesChartObjects data, _) => data.amount.toString(),
      colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault),

];
```

**The problem I have with this way is:**

I accept that a timeline chart wont put two layers on top of each other if the year is not the same in the two lists. So I am currently replacing the returned year of 2019 for example, with the current year so it maps them over each other nicely by date and month to look the way it does in the first image.

But when the list which I am replacing the year with the current year has data that is over two years, for example 15/12/2019 - 15/01/2020, I am also replacing 2019 with 2020 which messes the whole chart up **off course** and puts the 2019 December data in the current year's December, and looks like this

[image]

I am looking for the right way to do this comparison and feel very stuck. Is there a standard way of doing a sales/date comparison chart?

I could use a line chart on it's own, but how do I display dates on the domain axis "26/08/2020" as it only accepts integers? Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the two layers to always line up together on dd/mm/yyyy, you need to make the dd/mm/yyyy the same for both.

My first layer will always fetch the current year.
The second layer any other year.
The "any other year" is where the yy needs to be switched to current yy. The problem is pulling data that spans over two years, for example 15 Dec 2019 - 15 Jan 2020. As you can't make them all "2020" as some are in 2019.

I managed to solve this issue by checking if the yy are all the same or not, and if not, change the smaller one of the two to current year - 1, and the larger year to the current year, as below.

I don't know if this makes sense to anyone but it works great, I cant imagine me being the only one looking for a year on year sales graph. This is not all the code required for a graph off course, but has the solution to the problem statement. I used provider to make the chartObjectsPrevious year available to the chart. The below code is what I do to the previous year date objects.

```
List<SalesChartObjects> chartObjectsPreviousYear = [];

chartObjectsPreviousYear = SalesChartModel.fromJson(jsonRaw).objects;
var firstDayFromRange = chartObjectsPreviousYear[1].dt.year;
var lastDayFromRange = chartObjectsPreviousYear[30].dt.year;

if (firstDayFromRange != lastDayFromRange) {
  chartObjectsPreviousYear.forEach((element) {
    if (element.dt.year == firstDayFromRange) {
      String pDay = element.dt.day < 10 ? "0${element.dt.day.toString()}" : element.dt.day.toString();
      String pMonth = element.dt.month < 10 ? "0${element.dt.month.toString()}" : element.dt.month.toString();
      int subtractOne = DateTime.now().year - 1;
      String pYear = subtractOne.toString();
      element.dt = DateTime.parse("$pYear-$pMonth-$pDay 00:00:00");
    } else {
      String pDay = element.dt.day < 10 ? "0${element.dt.day.toString()}" : element.dt.day.toString();
      String pMonth = element.dt.month < 10 ? "0${element.dt.month.toString()}" : element.dt.month.toString();
      String pYear = DateTime.now().year.toString();
      element.dt = DateTime.parse("$pYear-$pMonth-$pDay 00:00:00");
    }
  });
} else {
  chartObjectsPreviousYear.forEach((element) {
    String cDay = element.dt.day < 10 ? "0${element.dt.day.toString()}" : element.dt.day.toString();
    String cMonth = element.dt.month < 10 ? "0${element.dt.month.toString()}" : element.dt.month.toString();
    String cYear = DateTime.now().year.toString();
    element.dt = DateTime.parse("$cYear-$cMonth-$cDay 00:00:00");
  });
}
```